# Apache Beam Error - AsList object is not iterable

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to make a side input from a pcollection in apache beam with python.

This is my code:

```
from apache_beam.pvalue import AsList

locations_dim = p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
query='SELECT a, b, c, d FROM test.testing_table')) | 
beam.Map(format_apply)

AsList(locations_dim) | WriteToText(known_args.output)
```

(I apply WritToText in order to debug)
But it raises the following error:

```
self.value = tuple(value)
TypeError: 'AsList' object is not iterable
```

Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to write each element individually to the text file? Or are you trying to write the whole collection as a list into the file? In any case, the result of `AsList` can not be used as a main input for another PTransform. It can only be used as a side input

Comment: Did you get an answer/solution for this error ?

Answer (score 0):

`AsList` is meant to be used for [side inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs). In this case, you should be able to directly write

`locations_dim | WriteToText(known_args.output)`